# Why can't I export the sample points successfully?

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, sample

[image]I selected the sample points for the classification of cultivated land in Uzbekistan, but I could not derive the sample points. Why? I've set maxpixels!
Here's my code

```
// region
var uzbekistan = countries.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM0_NAME', 'Uzbekistan'));
//remove clouds
var roi = uzbekistan;
Map.addLayer(roi,{'color':'grey'},'roi');
// Map.centerObject(roi,5);
// Applies scaling factors.
function applyScaleFactors(image) {
  var opticalBands = image.select('SR_B.').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2);
  // var thermalBands = image.select('ST_B.*').multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0);
  return image.addBands(opticalBands, null, true)
              // .addBands(thermalBands, null, true);
}

// reomove cloud for Landsat-8
function cloudRemoval(image) { 
  // 
  var cloudShadowBitMask = (1 << 4); 
  var cloudsBitMask = (1 << 3); 
  var qa = image.select('QA_PIXEL'); 
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0) 
                 .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0)); 
  var mask2 = image.select("blue").gt(0.2);                 
  return image.updateMask(mask).updateMask(mask2.not()).toDouble()
              .copyProperties(image)
              .copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"]);
} 

// 计算 NDVI
function calculateNDVI(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(["nir", "red"]).rename("NDVI");
  return image.addBands(ndvi);
}

// Assign a common name to the sensor-specific bands.
var LC9_BANDS = ['SR_B2','SR_B3','SR_B4','SR_B5','SR_B6','SR_B7','QA_PIXEL']; //Landsat 9
var LC8_BANDS = ['SR_B2','SR_B3','SR_B4','SR_B5','SR_B6','SR_B7','QA_PIXEL']; //Landsat 8
var LC7_BANDS = ['SR_B1','SR_B2','SR_B3', 'SR_B4','SR_B5','SR_B7','QA_PIXEL']; //Landsat 7
var LC5_BANDS = ['SR_B1','SR_B2','SR_B3', 'SR_B4','SR_B5','SR_B7','QA_PIXEL']; //Llandsat 5
var S2_BANDS  = ['B2','B3','B4','B8','B11','B12']; // Sentinel-2
var STD_NAMES = ['blue', 'green', 'red', 'nir', 'swir1', 'swir2','QA_PIXEL'];

var year = 2022;
var month_start = 1;
var month_end = 12;

var L9Col = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC09/C02/T1_L2')
                .filterBounds(roi)
                .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(year,year,'year'))
                .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(month_start,month_end,'month'))
                .map(applyScaleFactors)
                .select(LC9_BANDS,STD_NAMES)
                .map(cloudRemoval)
                .map(calculateNDVI);
var L8Col = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2')
                .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(year,year,'year'))
                .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(month_start,month_end,'month'))
                .map(applyScaleFactors)
                .select(LC8_BANDS,STD_NAMES)
                .map(cloudRemoval)
                .map(calculateNDVI);
var L7Col = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C02/T1_L2')
                .filterBounds(roi)
                .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(year,year,'year'))
                .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(month_start,month_end,'month'))
                .map(applyScaleFactors)
                .select(LC7_BANDS,STD_NAMES)
                .map(cloudRemoval)
                .map(calculateNDVI);
var L5Col = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C02/T1_L2')
                .filterBounds(roi)
                .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(year,year,'year'))
                .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(month_start,month_end,'month'))
                .map(applyScaleFactors)
                .select(LC5_BANDS,STD_NAMES)
                .map(cloudRemoval)
                .map(calculateNDVI);
                
//l8Col.merge(l7Col).merge(S2Col)
var LandsatCol = ee.ImageCollection(L9Col.merge(L8Col).merge(L7Col).merge(L5Col))
                .sort("system:time_start")
                // .map(addIndex);
print("LandsatCol",LandsatCol.limit(5));

var visParam = {
  bands:["swir1","nir","red"],
  min: 0.0,
  max: 0.3,
  maxPixels:1e10
};
Map.addLayer(LandsatCol.min().clip(roi), visParam, 'LandsatCol');

// 创建 NDVI 时间序列图表
var ndviTimeSeries = ui.Chart.image.series({
  imageCollection: LandsatCol.select("NDVI"),
  region: roi,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 30,
  xProperty: 'system:time_start'
}).setOptions({
  title: 'NDVI 时间序列图表',
  vAxis: {title: 'NDVI'},
  hAxis: {title: '日期'},
});
print(ndviTimeSeries);

// 注册地图点击事件
Map.onClick(function(coords){
  var lon = coords.lon;
  var lat = coords.lat;
  print("点击点坐标: ", lon, lat);
  
  var point = ee.Geometry.Point(lon, lat);
  
  var ndviTimeSeriesPoint = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
    imageCollection: LandsatCol.select("NDVI"),
    regions: point,
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    scale: 30,
    xProperty: 'system:time_start',
    seriesProperty: 'NDVI'
  }).setChartType('ScatterChart').setOptions({
    title: 'NDVI 时间序列散点图',
    vAxis: {title: 'NDVI'},
    hAxis: {title: '日期'},
  });
  print(ndviTimeSeriesPoint);
});

// Merge points together
var sampleCollection =LandsatCol.merge(Cotton).merge(Mazie).merge(Rice).merge(WheatandOther).merge(Alfalfa).merge(Other).merge(Wheat);
print(sampleCollection , 'Sample Collection ')

//Export
Export.table.toDrive({
collection: sampleCollection,
description: 'Sample Feature Collection',
maxPixels:1e10
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For too many pixels error you need to reduce spatial resolution (scale) in your code. For example if you set scale as 30 must be reduced to 100 or even higher value. Try with 100 first, if it didn't work increase to 250 or 500.

Regarding to 5000 image collection, each variable must be included less than 5000 elements.

Comment: Thanks especially for your answer.  I'm just starting to use gee and learn the code. I would also like to ask how I should operate in detail? How can I write code to do what you're saying?

Comment: change the scale argument in ndviTimeSeries and ndviTimeSeriesPoints to 100 or 250.

Comment: thank you a lot! now I am going to try~

Comment: but it still noticed me that:ImageCollection (Error)Collection query aborted after accumulating over 5000 elements. Why would it happened?

Comment: Would you share your code through get link? because I want to check it out accurately.

Comment: sry, i did not check this message immediately and did not reply you on time. But i solved this problem. really thanks for your help, sir.

Comment: Welcome. if the answer helped you in this regard please accept the answer.